# how to save the selected layer for the web in PS CS6?

Tags: photoshop

how to save the selected layer for the web in PhotoShop CS6? I've a PSD design and I only want to save the logo as png. How Can I do this in Photoshop cs6? Is there any shortcut for this?

Thanks in Advance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hide all other layers! Select your layer then, alt + click on eye symbol. that hides all layers except selected one. then save for web

to copy it in a new Document:
Select the layer you want to export to a new file.
In the top menu, Click "Layer" --> "Duplicate Layer..."
the second option is for the destination. select "New"

Comment: It saving the canvas size logo. But I want the exact size of logo.

Comment: for that you have to put it in a new document. updated answer